# Socket.IO server hangs up

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, long-polling

I am new to socket.io. So my socket.io server sometimws crashes giving this below error

```
timers.js:103
        if (!process.listeners('uncaughtException').length) throw e;
                                                                  ^
Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (http.js:1360:15)
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage._writeRaw (http.js:507:26)
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage._send (http.js:476:15)
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (http.js:749:16)
    at XHRPolling.doWrite (E:\sitesroot\0\node_modules\socket.io\lib\transports\
xhr-polling.js:67:17)
    at XHRPolling.HTTPPolling.write (E:\sitesroot\0\node_modules\socket.io\lib\t
ransports\http-polling.js:132:8)
    at XHRPolling.Transport.packet (E:\sitesroot\0\node_modules\socket.io\lib\tr
ansport.js:515:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\sitesroot\0\node_modules\socket.io\lib\transports\
http-polling.js:79:12)
    at Timer.list.ontimeout (timers.js:101:19)
```

It doesnt show where or why the error is happening so pretty sure its nothing to do with the code i have written. Could be something with the transports? I dont have much knowledge on it. Any suggestions on how to stop it from crashing would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: which version of node are you using? I strongly recommend you to install the latest stable one

Comment: this error is mostly seen in node v8.20

Comment: Am using v8.20, which version is the most stable? I am using azure node.js sdk and I read somewhere that v8.21 might cause some issues with azure sdk.....any idea which version should I use when using azure sdk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is as @miktam stated.
To fix this you need to add an error listener to your code.
Add this code to your application:

```
//Error handler
process.on('uncaughtException', function (exception) {
  // handle or ignore error
  console.log(exception);
});
```

When ever there is an error it will console.log it instead of crashing it. I had the exact same problem and this fixed it.

Comment: Upvoted... Simple solution but it was very frustrating til I reached here... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check this [issue](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/issues/1541)

Quoting Isaac Schlueter:

> The good news is that you're no longer leaking memory. The bad news is
>   that you do indeed need to add error listeners to your objects.
>
> In most apps, you can usually treat ECONNRESET as roughly the same as
>   a graceful close. Just make sure that you actually stop using that
>   socket, since it's now closed. However, it's not a graceful close,
>   since it's not in any sense "graceful". Prior to v0.8.20, node would
>   happily buffer all writes to reset sockets, causing memory explosion
>   death.

Answer (score 0):

For us new to websocket, you might be missing some parameters that are required by socket.io library.

What you might be using is `ws://localhost` which works for Websocket library, but might need to use `ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket` when using socket.io