# Nodejs http-proxy server crash on socket.io connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, proxy, cluster-computing

I have issue on my **Nodejs proxy server** with **socket hang up error**.

Server crashes when refreshing browser on 'app.example.com'. Connection working as it should be and page is loading correctly.

I'm using **http**, **http-proxy**, **cluster**, **domain**, **express**, **socket.io** node modules.

I added code below to prevent crash, but it made every request **really slow**.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', err => { console.log('Uncaught Exception', err)}
```

What I'm doing wrong to have this issue? I tried to add connection check on socket.io and express.io and also to proxy server with domain module without any help.

Here is some pages I readed

http://www.clock.co.uk/blog/preventing-http-raise-hangup-error-on-destroyed-socket-write-from-crashing-your-nodejs-server

[How to debug a socket hang up error in NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814481/how-to-debug-a-socket-hang-up-error-in-nodejs)

[Socket.IO server hangs up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657873/socket-io-server-hangs-up)

["Error: socket hang up" with Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24079120/error-socket-hang-up-with-express)

What can cause this issue?

**proxy_server.js**

```
const http = require('http'),
      httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),
      domain = require('domain'),
      cluster = require('cluster'),
      numCpus = require('os').cpus().length

if(cluster.isMaster) {
    for(let i = 0;i < numCpus;i++) {
        cluster.fork()
    }

    cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
        console.log(`Worker ${worker.process.pid} closed at ${new Date()}\nRestarting`)
        cluster.fork()
    })
} else {

    const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
        let host = req.headers.host

        let reqd = domain.create()
        reqd.add(req)
        reqd.add(res)

        // On error dispose of the domain
        reqd.on('error', err => {
            console.log('Error', err, req.url)
            reqd.dispose()
        })

        let proxy = new httpProxy.createProxy({
            target: 'localhost'
        })

        let subdomain = host.split('.')[0]
        switch(subdomain) {
            case 'app':
                proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:3010' }, err => {  } )
                break
            default:
                proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:3000' }, err => {  } )
                break
        }
    }

    server.listen(80)
    server.on('upgrade', (req, socket, head) => {
        proxy.ws(req, socket, head)
    })
}
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express'),
      app = express()
      io = require('socket.io')(app),

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.socket.on('error', () => {
        console.log('Error on req socket')
    })
    res.socket.on('error', () => {
        console.log('Error on res socket')
    })
    next()
})

... my application configs ...

io.on('connection', socket => {
    if(socket.connected)
        socket.emit('connected', { response: { success: true } })
})

app.listen(3010)
```

**client.js**

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    let socket = io.connect('app.example.com')

    socket.on('connected', () => { console.log('✓ Socket connected!') }
    socket.on('disconnect', () => { console.log(' Socket disconnected!') }
    socket.on('error', (err) => { console.log(' Socket error!\n', err) }
}
```

These happen everytime when I refresh page on app.example.com, page loading normally and socket.io connection works normally, but somehow it crashes my proxyserver and cluster fork it up again.

**Client console.log**

```
✓ Socket connected!

WebSocket connection to 'ws://app.example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=sRs29QgeORgPFiIKAAAC' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
```

**Proxy service crash**

```
Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:250:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:342:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:926:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)

Worker 2208 closed at Wed May 11 2016 18:08:39 GMT+0300 (EEST)
Restarting
Worker 7153 started succesfully
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

✓ Found and fixed the problem

I removed this part, and **socket hang up error was gone!!**

```
server.on('upgrade', (req, socket, head) => {
    proxy.ws(req, socket, head)
})
```

This was documented on https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy nodejitsu github page and I tried that node-http-proxy but changed back to http-proxy module, but forgot to remove that part out. Finally it's working.

```
//
// Listen to the `upgrade` event and proxy the
// WebSocket requests as well.
//
proxyServer.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) {
   proxy.ws(req, socket, head);
});
```